# Connect to WCF RESTful service on local IIS from android device (Galaxy Note 3)

Tags: android, wcf, iis, httpclient

I'm building an android application that needs to connect to a WCF service. I developed a one and hosted it on my local IIS (7.5) on the following URL:`http://129.168.125.5/MyAppDomain/RESTService.svc`

(I used local IP address not localhost to avoid referring to the same device or using 10.0.0.2). It works fine on the emulator but When I tried to debug it from my active device connected via USB (galaxy note 3) using Eclipse,

```
I always got connection to http://129.168.125.5 refused
```

. *I also granted permission to INTERNET* in my manifest file. Any Help Please?

Here is my code sample:

```
Boolean res = false;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://129.168.125.5/MobileShopper/ShopperService.svc/Login");
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        try
          {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
            obj.put("email", mEmail);
            obj.put("password", mPassword);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity Hentity = response.getEntity();
            if(Hentity.getContentLength() != 0) {
                // stream reader object
                Reader JSONReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                //create a buffer to fill if from reader
                final char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
                //fill the buffer by the help of reader
                JSONReader.read(buffer);
                //close the reader streams
                JSONReader.close();

                if(new String(buffer).equals("1")){
                    res = true;
                }
                else
                    res = false;            
            }


          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
              return false;
          }
        return res;
```

Comment: http://minafayek.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/consuming-iis-published-restful-wcf-service-from-android-over-wifi/

Comment: The same error. I added security permissions on the IIS App folder for IIS_IUSERS and also for Everyone! and nothing changed.

Comment: I even turned windows firewall off to make sure that the connection isn't blocked by it and I still have the same ugly error!

Comment: @DigitalFox, did you find a solution? Locally for me, I get 400 Bad request.